# Parent accessing child

Tags: c++, c++11

I understand everything what is stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance), it describes how Child accesses Parent members. But, how about Parent Accessing Child? I just can't understand this. Why it is wrong? Could you please explain in terms of static binding rules during compile time? Here Student class itself becomes protected I guess, but why?

```
using namespace std;
class Person
{
public:
    int b;  
};

class Student : protected Person
{
public:
    int c;
};

int main()
{
    Student s;
    Person *pPerson;
    pPerson = &s;
    return 0;
}
```

C-T error:

> Error is: type cast: conversion from 'Student*' to 'Person*' exists, but is inaccessible

Comment: Sure, parent can technically access child, but How would parent keep track of children?

Comment: Please don't talk about "parent" and "child" - in C++ we talk about "base" and "derived", and there is no way for a base class to know about the features of a derived class, except for those that are also in the base class.

Comment: But there all methods are static (aka no virtual functions). In above assignment , even if derivation was public, there is no way Person could change or access anything in Student

Comment: @NeilButterworth , please don't lead post to unrelated topic, I think they are synonymous. And I don't think that any C++ people would be confused with Parent/Child instead of Base/Derived.

Comment: There are indeed cases where parent can access child properties, not necessarily in this example, but in others.
An example is to create an object of parent inside the child, then set that object to the child's parent. The child will then be able to access parent variables..etc   or vice versa

Comment: @Ess There are such cases when the two classes are very tightly bound. These cases are always instances of bad design.

Comment: @NeilButterworth - sometimes one must think outside the 'optimal design' box

Comment: @Ess Never happened for me - but please, post an answer illustrating what you are talking about and possibly also answering the OP's question.

Comment: Personally I do much Child to parent & Parent to child calls and references. Might not be best practice, but sometimes there are no better ways around it without rewriting several million lines of code

Comment: could you please clarify what you're asking? Could you explain what is either confusing or desired out of your code sample? "*Here Student class itself becomes protected I guess, but why?*" needs clarification

Comment: @vu1p3n0x , the question is why I can't do this pPerson = &s; in above example. I don't want to fix code. I just want to learn the reason why protected derivation makes this

Comment: Ah. That can be answered cleanly since you've already read the question I would use as a duplicate. `main` is not a member of the inheritance hierarchy so it does not know about the relationship between `Student` and `Person`. Only `Student` and classes derived from `Student` know that `Student` is derived from `Person`.

Comment: @user4581301 , hmm, so in derivation we are not just defining how members are inherited (aka how classes sees parent members), but also define how classes theirselves see each other , right? Or am I talking about same things?

Comment: Protected and Private inheritance works exactly the same as protected and private member declaration.

Comment: @GemTaylor, but if make all members protected in Student , and derivation public, things work

Comment: @user4581301 , I put an exception in code. Could you please explain like what type of conversion is that and where from it wants to call it? Maybe that will make things clear?

Comment: You are defining how the rest of the program sees the inheritance.  `main` cannot assign a `Student` to a `Person` without complaint (you've seen that in the error message above) and cannot access the `public` members of `Person` through a `Student`. Only Student or a a class derived from `Student` can.

Comment: @Sher but if you made member c protected, you would not be able to access the c part of Student from main. You made Person a protected base of Student and now you cannot access the person part of Student it from main. It works exactly the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not about how `Person` "sees" `Student`, its about what access control on inheritance *means*.

When you say `class Student: public Person`, it means you are announcing that a `Student` is a `Person` to everyone, that means `main()` knows a `Student*` can be referred to by a `Person*`. So all is good.

When you say `class Student: private Person`, it means `Student` is inheriting functionality from `Person`, but that is simply an implementation detail. This doesn't let anyone know a `Student` is a `Person` so it can't be considered as one. Therefore `main()` thinks `Student*` and `Person*` are unrelated.

When you say `class Student: protected Person`, its a little bit trickier but the process still applies. You are inheriting the functionality from `Person` and any derived class of `Student` also knows that. So if you had a class like `Freshman` that inherited from `Student`, it'd know it was also a `Person`. However, that is specific to the inherited classes, `main()` doesn't know `Student` is a `Person` because that knowledge is protected.